# Why, in many languages, must we deallocate dynamic arrays but not static ones?

Tags: arrays, memory, dynamic

I understand that the memory allocated for arrays are freed when the array goes out of scope, but why, in languages such as C, C++ and Fortran, don't dynamic arrays automatically get deleted when they go out of scope?

Comment: This question is a better fit for Software Engineering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why, in languages such as C, C++ and Fortran, don't dynamic arrays automatically get deleted when they go out of scope

Because the lifespan of dynamically-allocated objects is not scope-limited. Consider a function that allocates an object and then returns a pointer to it:

```
ObjectClass* createObject(size_t count) {

    ObjectClass* ptr = malloc( sizeof(ObjectClass) );
    ptr->someArraMember = calloc( sizeof(ArrayMember), count );
    return ptr;
}
```

If `ptr`'s memory were to be deallocated when it leaves scope (i.e. when `createObject` returns) then the pointer would be a "dangling pointer" and corrupt the program's memory if it were used:

```
ObjectClass* createObject(size_t count) {

    ObjectClass* ptr = malloc( sizeof(ObjectClass) );
    ptr->someArraMember = calloc( sizeof(ArrayMember), count );
    free( ptr );
    return ptr; // <-- NEVER DO THIS!
}
```

Static arrays, however, have their life limited by the scope, by-design, and are typically stack-allocated. Returning a pointer to a static array element after execution has left the array's scope results in undefined-behaviour (i.e. your program will crash... eventually).

```
int* getStaticArrayElement(size_t i) {

    int staticArray[100];
    return &staticArray[i]; // <-- NEVER DO THIS!
}
```

Remember that C is a very old language (dating from the 1960s) and is designed to be simple so things like Garbage Collection (too complicated) and reference-counting (too expensive) were removed and become the programmer's responsibility to implement) - also note the language predates more intelligent object lifetime analysis (that Go-lang has) or ownership semantics (like Rust has) which is why they are unavailable, and given the frequent requirement that a C runtime environment be as minimal and simple as possible means it's very unlikely we'll ever see those features added in future C language versions.

If you want a language that gives you the control that C has - with modern features like ownership semantics then use Rust: https://www.rust-lang.org/

Comment: This makes sense - what about the case where one deals with a pointer to a non-dynamic array which then goes out of scope?

Comment: PS - more modern languages aren't really accessible to me because I program things where mathematical computation times are the primary objective. I use python for less demanding tasks, which I can see has more sophisticated managing of these sorts of issues, but I can't use such languages for the crux of my tasks.

Comment: @obackhouse All languages that AOT-compile to native (C, C++, Fortran, Rust, etc) will have near-identical runtime performance for "mathematical" operations (I assume you mean integer and IEEE-754 arithmetic). If you really want hardcore floating math performance then use your GPUs.

Comment: I've come into the world of programming vertically from science rather than from computer science as you can probably tell. There is also a demand for high precision floating-point math as well in these tasks. What I can say is that all high-end software in the field uses C/C++/Fortran (the latter maybe being a bit of historical artefact)